# Compile Python code with Openpyxl into executable using PyInstaller Error cannot import '__versions__'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, openpyxl

I have searched the web for every solution I can think of for this problem. I have a python code that uses openpyxl to read from a excel spreadsheet. I want to give this code to a friend that does not have python installed, so I need to convert it to .exe and it seems PyInstaller is the best option. I downloaded PyInstaller and used it on a few test codes ("hello world" and whatnot) to make sure it worked and it seems to be installed properly. When I tried to compile the code I was working on, it seemed to work and made a .exe file, but when I ran the executable it gave the error "ImportError: cannot import name '__version_'". After tons of searching I found some information about using hooks, but when I tried to copy the hook it still didn't work. It seems the problem is the python version, the only information I could find was using Python 2.7 but I am using Python 3.5. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if I need to add more information just say what needs to be added.

Comment: Could you post a code sample and the stacktrace?

Comment: Which code sample? like the .py file or the .exe? And I'm still a bit new to some of this, what exactly is a stacktrace?

Comment: We only support distribution using pip.

Comment: I am fairly sure I used pip to install openpyxl, is there a way I can check? and the module works for the code, it functions just fine. I just can't compile it

Comment: The link of the old post helped, thank you! how do I mark this thread as answered?